# Ensure identifierForVendor in iOS is unique for all devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my project, I'm using `identifierForVendor` in iOS and storing it in the Keychain to define the iOS device.
How can I make sure that it is a unique ID for all iOS devices?

Here my code is:

```
-(NSString *)getUniqueDeviceIdentifierAsString
{

 NSString *appName=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey];

 NSString *strApplicationUUID = [SSKeychain passwordForService:appName account:@"incoding"];
 if (strApplicationUUID == nil)
 {
    strApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    [SSKeychain setPassword:strApplicationUUID forService:appName account:@"incoding"];
 }

 return strApplicationUUID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that you have to worry about. Apple (in their API documentation) has guaranteed that it is unique per device per app. If it wasn't, there would have been a lot of upset users and developers by now.

Secondly, you don't need to store it. It's not going to change. Simply access it when you need it.

Comment: Hi @Drekka. 
If I don't store it, the UUID will be change when I re- Install the application.

Comment: Can you give me document that ensure the API return the unique ID for all devices? 
ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor

Comment: Yes I thought of that. But it's generally a bad idea to leave data in the keychain if you uninstall an app and AFAIK Apple does not provide any guarantee that keychain data will be preserved. My recommendation would be to look at why you think you need to preserve data if the app is removed.

Comment: identifierForVendor IS NOT UNIQUE !!! it will change after app reinstall.